# Startex align with the multicolumn

Tags: multicol

**Original:**

[image]

**I want it like this: How can i do it?** (When I use the `enumerate`, I don't get the good result.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

\newcommand{\Startex}[1]{%
\noindent
\parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{%
    \vspace*{0.9cm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \textbf{1.}
#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

    \Startex{
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
       }
       
 \vfill\null
 \columnbreak      
 
 \Startex{
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
       }
 
 
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please specify why `enumerate` is not working for you?

Comment: Horizontal alignment imbalance occurs for enums to the right of the column. @Rmano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if you do or do not want hanging indentation. Either way, I suggest you load the `enumitem` package and use some of the package's options to achieve your formatting objective.

- If you do *not* want hanging indentation, use the option `wide=0pt`.
- Conversely, if you do want hanging indentation, use the option `left=0pt`.

I would further like to suggest that you employ the options `label=\bfseries\arabic*.` and `ref=\arabic*` with either type of `enumerate` setup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \label{aa}

\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \label{bb}
\end{enumerate}


\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,label=\bfseries\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,resume]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \label{cc}

\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \label{dd}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\hrule
\bigskip\noindent
Cross-references to items \ref{bb} and \ref{dd} of the enumerated list.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you :) ?@Mico

Comment: What is \label{aa} @Mico?

Comment: @cufcuf - The standard or basic way to generate cross-references in a LaTeX document is to place `\label` instructions where the items to be cross-referenced are located inside the document and `\ref` instructions where cross-references to these items should appear. Notice that, in my answer, there are four `\label` instructions -- one per enumerated `\item`; the answer also contains two `\ref` instructions.